# get_posts() and global variables

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, globals

I was reading this post: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts), which seems to have become the go-to post for understanding the difference between the different functions for making custom loops.

In the article, it says that

> [get_posts] doesn't modify global variables and is safe to use anywhere

Nonetheless, when I inserted into within another loop (I wanted to have a home page showing 3 columns, 2 done with custom fields, one with latest blog posts), I had to preserve the original $post, like so:

```
<?php global $post; // required
$tmp_post = $post; // save original post
args = array('numberposts' => 2); // Retrieve just 2 posts
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
    //My posts code here (removed to simplify)
<?php
endforeach;
$post = $tmp_post; //go back to original post
?>
```

Before I saved the original post, my third column, with the custom field, was blank, but after resetting, as above, it works fine.

Did I misunderstand what that line in the post meant? Did I do something I wasn't supposed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_posts` doesn't modify global variables & is safe to use anywhere but `setup_postdata` does modify the global variables.

Use the function `wp_reset_postdata()` just after the foreach loop. It reverses the changes made by `setup_postdata`. The thing it does is basically same as you did in your example, you just won't need to worry about the temporary variable.

Comment: I tried removing `setup_postdata` from my foreach, but I get the same problem. I still had to reset the post... Which also makes me wonder, what's the point of `setup_postdata` in the first place (nothing seemed to change after I deleted it)? I had it there because all the code examples I saw had it.

Comment: `setup_postdata` does only one thing, which is setting the global post data (this allows you to use template functions like `the_title()`). If you don't want to use them, you don't need `setup_postdata`. `get_posts` doesn't change anything, it probably is something else.

Comment: Here's the link to the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

Comment: You're right! I found the culprit, as usual, it was a plugin: Advanced Custom Fields. Thanks.